# GWT Hungarian DateTime

Tags: gwt, datetime

I live in Hungary and I want to create gwt programs.

**timestamp**

```
1324565400
```

**gwt html**

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=hu_HU">
```

**my code**

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormater = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("H:mm");
...
mikorColumnConfig.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<RendelesIdeiglenes>() {
    @Override
    public Object render(
        RendelesIdeiglenes model, String property,
        ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
        ListStore<RendelesIdeiglenes> store,
        Grid<RendelesIdeiglenes> grid)
    {
        return dateFormater.format((Date) model.get(property));
    }
 });
```

and gwt displays

> 15:50

but the real time is

> 14:50

Why does it display the wrong time? I belive it could have something to do with the day light saving time, how do I activate the *dayLightSaving* setting?

Comment: In your code, where do you specify the **locale**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well, `1324565400000` is 14:50 UTC, and 15:50 UTC+1, and I believe Hungary is in UTC+1, so, living in Hungary, your computer is in UTC+1, and thus expectedly displays *15:50*.

**Note:** the app's locale (as set with the `meta name="gwt:property"`) doesn't change the time-zone that applies. That one is always the one of the computer running the code, i.e. dates are always *local dates*, and are formatted as such unless you pass an explicit `TimeZone` to the `format` method.

---

BTW, you might want to use `DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.TIME_SHORT)` rather than `DateTimeFormat.getFormat("H:mm")`. The *short time* format in the `hu` locale is `H:mm` so you won't notice a change, but it'll be easier to internationalize it later on (if you add English support, you'll automatically use the appropriate *short time* format for the locale, contrary to `H:mm` which is fixed and locale independent).